# How to extract two pieces of data from a string

Tags: bash

I am trying to extract two pieces of data from a string and I have having a bit of trouble. The string is formatted like this:

`11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555 aaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbb:cccccccc:dddddddd`

What I am trying to achieve is to print the first column (11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555) and the third section of the colon string (cccccccc), on the same line with a space between the two, as the first column is an identifier. Ideally in a way that can just be run as one-line from the terminal.

I have tried using cut and awk but I have yet to find a good way to make this work.

Comment: Just to be clear, the output you're looking for is: `11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555 cccccccc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a sed expression like this?

```
echo "11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555 aaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbb:cccccccc:dddddddd" |
sed -e "s/\(.*\) .*:.*:\(.*\):.*/\1 \2/"
```

Result:

```
11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555 cccccccc
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `awk` script does the job without relying on the format of the first column.

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {RS=ORS=" "} NR==1; NR==2 {print $3}'
```

Use it in a pipe or pass the string as a file (simply append the filename as an argument) or as a here-string (append `<<< "your string"`).

**Explanation:**
Instead of lines this `awk` script splits the input into space-separated records (`RS=ORS=" "`). Each record is subdivided into `:`-separated fields (`-F:`). The first record will be printed as is (`NR==1;`, that's the same as `NR==1 {print $0}`). In the second record, we will only print the 3rd field (`NR==2 {print {$3}}`); in case of the record `aaa:bbb:ccc:ddd` the 3rd field is `ccc`.

Comment: Love this! `awk` is so great. Wish I understood it better

Comment: Glad to hear that. I added some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from user803422 is better but here's another option. Maybe it'll help you use `cut` in the future.

```
str='11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555 aaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbb:cccccccc:dddddddd'
first=$(echo "$str" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
second=$(echo "$str" | cut -d ':' -f6)
echo "$first $second"
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure Bash Regex:

```
str='11111111-2222:3333:4444:555555555555 aaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbb:cccccccc:dddddddd'
echo "$([[ $str =~ (.*\ ).*:.*:([^:]*) ]])${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Explanations:

- `[[ $str =~ (.*\ ).*:.*:([^:]* ]]`: Match `$str` against the POSIX Extended RegEx `(.*\ ).*:.*:([^:]*)` witch contains two capture groups: 1: `(.*\ )` 0 or more of any characters, followed by a space; and capture group 2: `([^:]*)` witch contains any number of characters that are not `:`.
- `$([[ $str =~ (.*\ ).*:.*:([^:]*) ]])`: execute the RegEx match in a sub-shell during the string value expansion. (here it produces no output, but the RegEx captured groups are referenced later).
- `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`: expand the content of the RegEx captured groups that Bash keeps in the dedicated `$BASH_REMATCH` array.